# How do I get my output to show asterisks for the amount in the input

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

In other words, if the input is 4, I want this to output 4 asterisks. I am writing a program that reads from a text file with random numbers in it. The program must read the number and then output that number of symbols to the console.  If the the number is even the program should output asterisk symbols, and if it is odd the output should be dollar signs.  For example, if the number 3 is read, then the output should be `$$$`, and if it were 4, then the output should be `****`. I wrote the program so it correctly outputs asterisks and dollar signs depending on if the number is even or odd, but I am not sure how to get it to output the correct number of symbols.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{ 
    int value, even, odd;
    char star='*';
    char dollarSign='$';
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("lab6_input.txt");
    infile >> value;

    while (infile >> value)
    {
        if (value % 2 == 0)
            cout << "*" << endl;
        else
            cout << "$" << endl;
        value++;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my current output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFDcG.jpg

**Note:** We are required to do this using while loops.

Comment: `cout << string(value, "*$"[value % 2]) << endl;`

Comment: Since you say you have to use while loops, think about the concept of counting down. How would you count down from say 5 to 0 using a while loop.  Now, if you need to output a character five times, using a while loop, just add an additional statement into the countdown loop that would print out your character. Once the loop has finished executing you will have printed out what you need to print.

Comment: paddy, when I paste that line in instead of the cout statements I currently have, it skips the first number (1) in my .txt file I'm reading from and then the program stops working when it reaches a negative number.

Comment: @AdamKeller nothing in the statement paddy gave you skips the 1st number in the file. Your own code does that, when it calls `infile >> value;` before the `while (infile >> value)` loop. And you didn't say anything about there being negative values in your file. What are they suppose to represent in this situation? Obviously, you can't process negative values the same way as positive values. What are you expected to output if you read a negative value?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Negative numbers should just be the same thing as other values, so like an absolute value of the negative numbers. These numbers don't represent anything, it is just random numbers in a .txt file.

Comment: @AdamKeller If you want to treat negative numbers the same as possible values (why?), then you have to drop their negative sign explicitly, such as by using the [`std::abs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) function: `while (infile >> value) { value = abs(value); ... }`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not entirely sure why either...

Answer (score -1):

Use a simple for loop. I am sure they were taught to you for this assignment. Recheck the curricula.

Example: to repeat an action `n` times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    // do action
```

Comment: We have to use while loops. It is on our rubric.

Comment: @AdamKeller `while (n > 0) { ... --n; }`

Comment: @AdamKeller so use while loop. I mean man, at least pretend to try a little.

Comment: I have been trying for a few hours I just don't understand. My program works correctly except that I have to output like a **** for 4 instead of just *.

Comment: @AdamKeller read again the course on while loop. Do some tutorials in that isn't enough. Get a good book and read the chapter on loops.